# Getting error when I run my program. What do I need to change?

Tags: python, string, integer, arguments, typeerror

```
      import random,  string

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits +     string.punctuation


def generate_random_password():
    length = int(input("How many characters in password? "))
    number_of_passwords = int(input("How many passwords would you     like? "))
    character_count = characters
    if character_count > str(length):
        print("To long, try again")
        return
    password = []
    for i in range(length):
        password.append(random.choice(characters))
        if character_count < str(length):
            random.shuffle(characters)
                for i in range(length - character_count):
                password.append(random.choice(characters))
        random.shuffle(password)
        output = "".join(password)
        print(output)
        return(output)

results = generate_random_password()

with open("pwd.txt", "w+") as file:
    file.write(results)
```

This the code for the generator and when I get to the end the result is the same:

```
    file.write(results)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

I tried the str function and int function; I changed "w+" to "a". I thought using the str function would fix it, considering the argument must be str.

Comment: This code cannot be run because it is not indented properly. I suggest you post a [mre] with valid indentation.

Comment: Figure out the cases where you `return None` (or simply `return`). A better way to report an error is by raising an exception; this way, the caller knows something went wrong.

Comment: Separately, it's usually better to avoid interactive prompts inside a function; have the caller prompt the user (or provide a default, or whatever) and make the function do only one thing.

Comment: Once you've fixed the indentation take a look at *random.choices()*. It will allow you to simplify your code. Also, why do you prompt for "How many passwords..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When taking user input that needs to be of a certain type (in this case *int*) you should always validate it.

Functions should do what their name suggests - nothing more.

The *random* modules has a *choices()* function which is ideal for your needs.

```
from random import choices
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation

CHARACTERS = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation

def generate_random_password(length):
    return ''.join(choices(CHARACTERS, k=length))

while True:
    try:
        if (length := int(input('How many characters in password? '))) > len(CHARACTERS):
            raise Exception(f'Maximum length is {len(CHARACTERS)}')
        password = generate_random_password(length)
        with open('pwd.txt', 'w') as pwd:
            pwd.write(password)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is now runnable. I edited it so that you can now generate a password of a specific length. Now, it's up to you to complete the code so that it can generate more than 1 password.

```
import random, string

characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)


def generate_random_password():
    length = int(input("How many characters in password?\n"))
    number_of_passwords = int(input("How many passwords would you like?\n"))
    character_count = len(characters)
    
    if length > character_count:
        print("Too long, try again")
        return -1

    password = []
    output = ""
    for i in range(length):
        output += "".join(random.sample(characters, length))
        password.append(output)
        print(output)
        return (output)


results = generate_random_password()

if results != -1:
    with open("pwd.txt", "w+") as file:
        file.write(results)
```